# How to modify home page content

Tags: home

I cannot see the home page content in the backend. I am going to Content -> Element -> Pages and also through configuration but no luck. Please help me thank you .

Answer (score 0):

have you checked in your theme or any module for the "cms_index_index.xml" layout

In Your theme
`app/design/frontend/YourTheme/ThemePackage/Magento_Cms/cms_index_index.xml`

In any module
`app/code/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

Or from the Admin panel
Go to Store -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default page
See which page is chosen. If it's empty. Create one and select it in the configuration

Answer (score 0):

Login in Admin dashboard, go to

**Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page**

you will find what page assigned as Home page and then you can edit that.